# Create longestPossible(longest_possible in python) helper function that takes 1 integer argument which is a maximum length of a song in seconds

Tags: python

**Am kind of new to coding,please help me out with this one with explanations:**

songs is an array of objects which are formatted as follows:

{artist: 'Artist', title: 'Title String', playback: '04:30'}

You can expect playback value to be formatted exactly like above.

Output should be a title of the longest song from the database that matches the criteria of not being longer than specified time. If there's no songs matching criteria in the database, return false.

Answer (score 0):

Either you could change playback, so that instead of a string, it's an integer (for instance, the length of the song in seconds) which you convert to a string for display, and test from there, or, during the test, you could take playback and convert it to its length in seconds, like so:

```
    def songLength(playback):
        seconds = playback.split(':')
        lengthOfSong = int(seconds[0]) * 60 + int(seconds[1])
        return lengthOfSong
```

This will give the following result:

```
    >>> playback = '04:30'
    >>> songLength(playback)
    270
```

I'm not as familiar with the particular data structure you're using, but if you can iterate over these, you could do something like this:

```
    def longestPossible(array, maxLength):
        longest = 0
        songName = ''
        for song in array:
            lenSong = songLength(song.playback) # I'm formatting song's playback like this because I'm not sure how you're going to be accessing it.
            if maxLength >= lenSong and (maxLength - lenSong) < (maxLength - longest): 
                longest = lenSong
                songName = song.title
        if longest != 0:
            return songName
        else:
            return '' # Empty strings will evaluate to False.
```

I haven't tested this, but I think this should at least get you on the right track. There are more Pythonic ways of doing this, so never stop improving your code. Good luck!